# weather API forecast system in c#

Tags: c#, xml

i want to display 7 days of the weeks. weather information 
this is api i used to for getting 7 days result of london

```
http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=[APIKEY]&q=india&days=7
```

if i write code in c# below i should be no problem

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
          sb.Append("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=[APIKEY]&q=");  
          sb.Append(txtbox.Text);  
          sb.Append("&days=");  
          sb.Append("7");
```

this is code i written to display on data grid view but no result display
can any one fix the code for me to display 7 days weather information will display on data grid view

```
XmlReader xmlFile;
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(sb);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I don't see how your code could even compile, as there's no `XmlReader.Create(StringBuilder)` method as far as I can see. You need to separate your problem into "fetching the XML" and "displaying the XML". Then you can address that problem, and move onto the next.

Comment: @JonSkeet `static XmlReader.Create(string inputUri)` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you write code for me it will great help for me

Comment: @KevinSmith: Right, but the type of `sb` is `StringBuilder`, not `string`, and there's no implicit conversion from `StringBuilder` to `string`.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. You need to do the diagnostic work yourself, and write a [good, specific question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) showing the effort you've put in to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just `ToString()` the `StringBuilder`:

```
XmlReader xmlFile;
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(sb.ToString());
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

You might want to however checkout `HttpClient` as consuming a web service with `XmlReader.Create` feels just plain dirty

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZSTOhq

Comment: thanks, alot sir. how to display 7 days result in data grid view control.please help me thanks again

Comment: Maybe you should check out apiux c# client - https://github.com/apixu/apixu-csharp